# How do I apply NTFS permissions to protect user profiles?

Tags: active-directory, user-management, user-permissions

I want to set NTFS permissions on a users home directory so that one user cannot access another users home directory. How do I go about doing that? I need to be able to apply this to hundreds of users at once. It would be great to be able to batch apply permissions. I have a folder of UserProfiles and within that it has all the users home directories. Will this happen automatically when the home directories are created.

I read somewhere that I can use the %username% variable, but I don't know how to do that. I am not to sure whether that would work.

I'm just getting started in server administration.

Comment: This generally happens by default, when the user logs in.  If your installation is odd, you might be able to use powershell or batch.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.powershell.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm a contrarian and think that Microsoft's built-in functionality to allow client computers to automatically create profile folders is wrong. (Having a world-writable folder on a server, in my opinion, is a security problem.) This also gives me an excuse to pontificate about how I handle user data storage on Windows Server computers.

I'll give the caveat that I do everything I'm talking about below with a provisioning script, but there's no reason you couldn't do it all manually. For any large number of users, though, it makes sense to write even a simple batch script.

I *love* the [Folder Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx) functionality in Group Policy, and along with Roaming User Profiles, you can get close to stateless client computers. This does mean creating hierarchies of folders on server computers to handle storing the user data folders. Over the years I've come up with a way of doing it that I think gives a wonderful sysadmin user experience. (You mention that you're new to this-- you should definitely take some time to read about how these features worked-- "future you" will be glad that you did.)

I create a shared folder on the server computer-- something like "users", with a top-level permission of "Administrators / Full Control", "System / Full Control", and "Authenticate Users / List Folder Contents - This Folder Only". This allows unprivileged users to enumerate the contents of the folder but prevents needing to block inheritance of permissions at lower levels (which is *always* a sign that your design is "upside down" and limits your future flexibility).

If I had some top-level delineation of user accounts ("Employee" versus "Contractor", "Student" versus "Teacher", etc) I might do that off the top level folder (with the caveat that I wouldn't do this for categorizations that might change with any frequency because moving a user's "stuff" around is a pain). This can make Folder Redirection Group Policy a bit more complicated so I'd avoid this unless you need it.

I create a subfolder for each user account (named based on their username) and apply the permission "User / Full Control" to the subfolder. This is the only permission that I apply.

Below the user's folder I create subfolders for their redirected folders ("AppData", "Desktop", "Documents", etc) and "Profile.V2" (and "Profile" if I still need Windows XP compatibility):

```
[ ] - [ Users ]
        |
        - [ EAnderson ]  (<-- Permission EAnderson/Full Control applied here)
            |
            - [ AppData ]
            |
            - [ Desktop ]
            |
            - [ Documents ]
            |
            - [ Profile ]
            |
            - [ Profile.V2 ]
```

The workflow I'd use, in a manual environment, would be to initially create the user's account in AD w/o specifying the Profile or Home Directory paths. Then I'd go create the user's folder hierarchy, and apply permission before returning to the user's account properties and specifying the Profile and Home Directory paths. The paths for `EAnderson` would be set, in this example, to:

- Profile: `\\server\Users\EAnderson`
- Home Directory: `\\server\Users\EAnderson\Documents`

The "Active Directory Users and Computers" tool will "helpfully" ask you about changing permissions on folders when you specify user's Profile and Home Directory locations. I always tell that tool "No" because I don't want it messing w/ my manicured permissions.

My Folder Redirection policy would redirect the paths as follows:

- AppData: `\\server\Users\%username%\AppData`
- Desktop: `\\server\Users\%username%\Desktop`
- Documents: `\\server\Users\%username%\Documents`

In the Folder Redirection settings I always untick the box to "Grant the user exclusive rights to..." for each redirection entry (because this screws-up your manicured permissions, too).

If I had to contend with users still using Windows XP-based computers I'd also do a "Favorites" redirection into the legacy "Profile" folder, but hopefully you don't have to contend with that.

**Caution:** The "Do not check for user ownership of Roaming Profile Folders" Group Policy setting must be enabled for the roaming user profile to work properly. Back in Windows XP Service Pack 1 (and Windows 2000 Server Pack 4) Microsoft decided that, by default, the OS would check that the user was specified as the owner of their profile folder-- functionality that I disagree with and eliminate via enabling this Group Policy setting.

I like user data storage using this method for a number of reasons:

- It gives me a single permission to set for each user (or to reset when I have a replacement user who needs access to the old user's data).
- It gives me a single folder to assess a given user's disk space impact on a server computer (since all "their stuff" is stored in that one hierarchy).
- It limits the number of shared folder hierarchies I need to export from my server computer (as opposed to the "old way" that I did it-- with separate `\\server\profile`, `\\server\documents`, etc, hierarchies).